# Connect Oracle via Batch file

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I am very new to windows batch program. I have one requirement, i.e., I want to get the Oracle database username password & connection string from the user via command prompt. Depends on the user input I need to connect a particular user in the Oracle.  How can I do that using Windows batch file?

I tried, but I can't solve the problem.

```
enter code here
@ECHO OFF
ECHO *****************************
ECHO     Database Login
ECHO *****************************


SET /p username    =User/Schema:
SET /p passwd      =Password   :
SET /p tns         =Database   :


sqlplus %username%/%passwd%@%tns
```

When I execute the batch file I don't see any action, it just runs and exits from the command prompt.

Comment: run that command prompt with admin rights since oracle needs it

Answer (score 1):

or more simpler way is :

> sqlplus %1%/%2%@%3%

here %1 %2 %3 are the arguments you pass via command line. 
Like C:>sql_connect.bat admin asa123 orcl

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO *****************************
ECHO     Database Login
ECHO *****************************

SET /p usr=username: 
SET /p pwd=password: 
SET /p tns=tns: 

sqlplus %usr%/%pwd%@%tns%
```